# lxml not getting updated webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

Simple script here, i'm just trying to get the number of people in a gym from a webpage every 15 minutes and save the result in a text file. However, the script is outputting the result from the first time I ran it (39), as opposed to the updated number of 93 (which can be seen by refreshing the webpage). Any ideas why this is? Note, I set the time to sleep to 10 seconds incase you want to run it yourself.

```
from lxml import html
import time
import requests

x = 'x'

while x == x: 


    time.sleep(10)
    page = requests.get('http://www.puregym.com/gyms/holborn/whats-happening')
    string = html.fromstring(page.content)

    people = string.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="people-number"]/text()[last()])')
    print people
    #printing it for debug purposes

    f = open("people.txt","w")
    f.write(people)
    f.write("\n")
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the `people.txt` file after each loop, it is better to use Python's `with` function to do this as follows:

```
from lxml import html
import time
import requests

x = 'x'

while x == 'x': 
    time.sleep(10)
    page = requests.get('http://www.puregym.com/gyms/holborn/whats-happening')
    string = html.fromstring(page.content)

    people = string.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="people-number"]/text()[last()])')
    print people
    #printing it for debug purposes

    with open("people.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(people))
```

If you want to keep a log of all entries, you would need to move the with statement outside your while loop. Also I think you meant `while x == 'x'`. Currently the site is showing `39`, which is seen in the `people.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears that the website is unreliable, for some reason i'm now getting 56 on chrome (my main browser) and 39 on IE and firefox, which makes my project not really that useful. I'm still confused about the with statement though, when I move just the with statement and indent everything underneath I simply get indentation errors, and if I were to move with and f.write then it simply wouldn't work. Apologies for my confusion.

Comment: I only see 39 everywhere are the moment. Chrome on my phone also shows 39. Are you sure you are doing a proper refresh? Try holding shift when refreshing.

Comment: Tried shift refresh, didn't do anything, so I cleared my cookies for the site and that updated it to 39. Either way, I doubt the number of people in the gym has stayed constant for the past 4 hours.

Comment: Suggest you log each entry with a timestamp for a day, you might find they only update it every 30mins or something.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, will do. Cheers.